# My calculator has an odd orange button on it

Tags: color

I have this calculator with an all-around grayscale design, except an odd bright orange subtraction button. Why is it orange?[image]

Comment: This is, perhaps with more detail, a question for the [ux.se] site

Comment: Yeah, probably. I didn't really know where to put this question.

Answer (score 2):

It's typical for "ancient" ledgers to post on paper in red ink. The expression "in the red" has long meant to be in debt.

The association with red ink and negative (subtraction) numbers resulted in this coloration for some calculator designs.

Source: lived long enough to remember red ink in ledgers and "new-fangled" calculators.

Comment: Thats also the reason for the saying "in the red"